# Show a parametric family is an implicit solution of the following differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation:

$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{y(y^3-2x^3)}{x(2y^3-x^3)}$

Family:

$x^3 + y^3 = 3Cxy$

From this, I end up getting:

$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{Cy-x^2}{y^2-Cx}$

The missing step would be to put in the form given at the top. How is this possible?

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $3xy$ and substitute for $3Cxy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you multiply by xy in both numerator and denominator and then substituting the family equation? Try it out! What you had is correct by the way!

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Diving by $xy$ we get
$$
3C=\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{xy}=x^2y^{-1}+x^{-1}y^2,
$$
then differentiating we get
$$
(2xy^{-1}-x^{-2}y^2)dx+(-x^2y^{-2}+2x^{-1}y)dy=0
$$
therefore

\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=&-\dfrac{2xy^{-1}-x^{-2}y^2}{(-x^2y^{-2}+2x^{-1}y)}\\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=&-\dfrac{x^{-2}y^{-1}(2x^3-y^3)}{x^{-1}y^{-2}(-x^3+2y^3)}\\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=&-\dfrac{y(2x^3-y^3)}{x(-x^3+2y^3)}\\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=&\dfrac{y(y^3-2x^3)}{x(2y^3-x^3)}
\end{eqnarray}